# apply a function in the j section of a data.table that only works on one value of vector at a time

Tags: r, data.table

A possible duplicate is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673662/applying-a-function-to-each-row-of-a-data-table) but it does not help me. My case is different perhaps.

Consider a sample data.table.

```
set.seed(21)
DT <- data.table(col1=sample(x=1:10,size = 5),col2=sample(x=10:20,size=5))
DT
   col1 col2
1:    8   20
2:    3   11
3:    6   19
4:    2   17
5:   10   15
```

And consider a function `check` I want to apply to each row:

```
check <- function(x,y) if ((y-x)>10) "A" else "B"
```

Now if I run this assignment by reference calling the function `check` in the `j` section of `DT`, it fails miserably,

```
DT[,state:=check(col1,col2)]
```

And throws this warning

```
Warning message:
In if ((y - x) > 10) "A" else "B" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Obviously, I guessed that data.table processes the whole vector at once and the function needs one value so I thought the last value is the current value in the vector so I made this change, which seems another stupid move :-)

```
DT[,state:=check(last(col1),last(col2))]

DT

   col1 col2 state
1:    8   20     B
2:    3   11     B
3:    6   19     B
4:    2   17     B
5:   10   15     B
```

I see the `check()` function was computed for the last value and overwrote all previous values every time. What I want is this output:

```
 DT

   col1 col2 state
1:    8   20     A
2:    3   11     A
3:    6   19     A
4:    2   17     A
5:   10   15     B
```

So how do I make a function call work in a data.table for each row independently?

**ACTUAL FUNCTION:**
After I received a suggestion from *akrun* to use `ifelse`, which works fine for a simple condition like `check()` but I have a slightly more complicated function here. So please replace `check` by `allowed_state`

```
allowed_state <- function(old=NULL,new=NULL){
legalst<-data.table(from=c(1,1,9,9,7,8,7,10,10,11,11,10,11,8,7),to=c(11,7,10,7,8,7,9,9,7,1,7,1,7,9,10)) # all legal state transitions for a user
if(new %in% legalst[from==old,to]) "Legal" else "Illegal state change"
```

}

Comment: YOu need `ifelse` instead of `if/else` i.e. `check <- function(x,y) ifelse((y-x)>10, "A", "B")`

Comment: actually, my actual function `check` is not that simple to convert to ifelse. Unless you can suggest a way to convert it. Let me add my actual function also, in the question.

Comment: that would be helpful

Comment: @akrun could you look up the actual function (added) and now let's see how `ifelse` can be applied. I tried but there's a different warning about the size of the vector. It is not happy with the `legalst[from==old,to]` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, the OP wants to mark those state changes which are legal or illegal according to a given table `legalst` of legal state changes.

This can solved using an *update on join*:

```
set.seed(21)
DT <- data.table(col1 = sample(x = c(1, 7:11), size = 5),
                 col2 = sample(x = c(1, 7:11), size = 5))
legalst <- data.table(from = c(1,1,9,9,7,8,7,10,10,11,11,10,11,8,7), 
                      to = c(11,7,10,7,8,7,9,9,7,1,7,1,7,9,10))

DT[legalst, on = .(col1 = from, col2 = to), state := "Legal"][
  is.na(state), state := "Illegal state change"][]
```

> ```
>    col1 col2                state
> 1:   10   11 Illegal state change
> 2:    7    1 Illegal state change
> 3:    8   10 Illegal state change
> 4:    1    8 Illegal state change
> 5:   11    7                Legal
> ```

Comment: Brilliant. This is better as it does not need an extra function as well. I will accept your answer.